# Sharing files from an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I've written an iPhone app that uses [CocoaHttpServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to share the Documents/ folder of the app. This works very well, and I can list the files over WiFi from my Windows machine using a browser. (eg. http://192.168.1.4:424242 ). The only downside is that users have to save the file from the browser before they can actually use it.

But what I would like to know is if I could make the files appear inside Windows Explorer like the network shares (eg. \\192.168.1.70). What protocol is needed for this case? Is it smb (samba)?

I am also a little confused about Bonjour. Will Bonjour be useful in conjunction with the http server scheme I am using?

My goal is to provide a convenient way for users to access these files from Windows as well as OS X.

Regards

MV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an http server implemented you may want to read up on WebDAV and see if you can extend CocoaHttpServer to support it.  Would be a fun project.